# Serpapi not showing ad results

Tags: serpapi

I am using the following python code to get the ad results for a query:

However, there are no ad results coming through on the response. When I google search "pest control" I see that there are search ads.

Is there a reason serpapi is not capturing the ad postings?

```
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "q": "pest control",
  "location": "Halifax, Nova Scotia, Canada",
  "hl": "en",
  "gl": "ca",
  "api_key": "API_KEY"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()
ads = results["ads"]

print(ads)
```

I used the above code to find the ads

Comment: it's quite hard to know why it's appearing for one query but not another. FWIW, making the location "Nova Scotia, Canada" and removing the gl parameter makes it work

Answer (score 0):

It depends on Google search results and how the ads are set up. As [@mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4145280/mark) suggested, ads are shown in search without location (`gl` and `hl`) parameters.

[image: SerpApi Playground showing Google Ads]